# ¿Cómo conectarse a diferentes bases de datos mysql con php desde android studio?

Tags: php, java, mysql, android, android-volley

Buen día actualmente estoy presentando un problema me explico, yo tengo una aplicación que funciona con una base de datos `MySQL` para hacer las consultas utilizo `PHP` y `Volley` hasta aquí todo normal, sin embargo en mi aplicación requiero que se use para diferentes empresas, por ejemplo si mi aplicación funciona para Coca Cola también quiero que funcione para Pepsi sin hacer dos aplicaciones distintas, entonces esto simplemente lo hago creando una base de datos nueva donde tenga una tabla que aloja todas las empresas con su información entonces en la pantalla principal de mi aplicación muestro en un `RecyclerView` las empresas que tengo alojadas en la tabla hasta aquí todo normal también, ahora viene el problema, cuando yo selecciono por ejemplo Coca Cola pues inicia con su Splash, sus colores, su información, y todo lo que requiera de la base de datos, ahora bien si quiero que la aplicación funcione para Pepsi me he creado otra base de datos solo para Pepsi que obtenga su propia información sin embargo no logro hacer el cambio de la base de datos de Coca Cola a Pepsi desde android, a continuación mostrare lo que he intentado hacer:

Para esto utilizo una conexión:

**conn.php**

```
<?php

$root = 'Mi localhost';
$usuario = 'Mi usuario';
$password = 'Mi contraseña';
$base = 'El nombre de mi base de datos ';

$mysqli = new mysqli($root, $usuario, $password, $base);

if($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    die("Fallo la conexion");
} else {
   
}

?>
```

Este host lo utilizo en mis archivos PHP que utilizo para obtener información por ejemplo en el splash principal obtengo de la base de datos algunos recursos como colores, imágenes, etc., y funciona de la siguiente manera:

**ObtenerEmpresa.php**

```
<?php

require "conn.php";

$sql = "SELECT nombre_empresa, logo_empresa, correo_empresa, facebook_empresa, animacion_empresa, red, green, blue FROM empresa";
$query = $mysqli->query($sql);

$datos = array();

while($resultado = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $datos[] = $resultado;
}

echo json_encode(array("Empresa" => $datos));

mysqli_close($mysqli);

?>
```

Como se han dado cuenta al principio tengo un `require "conn.php";` esto claramente funciona para obtener la conexión que se hace a `MySQL`

Algo que había pensado hacer es crear diferentes conexiones a `MySQL` con sus propias bases de datos pero como sabría Android Studio cual conexión necesita depende de la selección? creo que seria un lio diferente?

Bien, ahora si nos vamos a Android Studio tengo una pantalla principal donde obtengo los tipos de negocio, aunque esto ya seria otro tema lo que si seria importante es al momento de seleccionar el tipo de negocio que me haga el cambio de base de datos por ejemplo si selecciono Coca-Cola que me seleccione la base de datos de Coca-Cola si selecciono Pepsi que seleccione la base de datos de Pepsi pero no logro encontrar una forma que me haga el cambio de base de datos desde Android Studio.

Algo que vale la pena mencionar es que tengo una base de datos "Madre" donde están todas las empresas que obtengo en la pantalla principal entonces algo que pensé es que podría obtener el id de empresa por ejemplo en un `if` como lo explico a continuación:

En primer lugar nos vamos al adaptador de los negocios:

```
negociosViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Obtener el id del negocio
            ObtenerNegocios.idNegocio = listaNegocios.get(posicion).getIdNegocio();

            if (ObtenerNegocios.idNegocio == 1){ //El id 1 pertenece a Coca-Cola
            //Obtener el la base de datos de Coca-Cola


                //Intencion al splash dependiendo del id del negocio
                cContext.startActivity(new Intent(cContext, SplashPrincipal.class));
                
            }
            
            else if (ObtenerNegocios.idNegocio == 2){ //El id 2 pertenece a Pepsi
            //Obtener la base de datos de Pepsi


                //Intención al Splash dependiendo del id del negocio y la conexión
                cContext.startActivity(new Intent(cContext, SplashPrincipal.class));
            }
        }
    });
```

Por si se preguntan el `ObtenerNegocios.idNegocio` lo obtengo con `Volley` en la clase **ObtenerNegocios.php** de la siguiente manera:

```
idNegocio = jsonObject1.getInt("id_negocio");
```

Cuando seleccionamos el tipo de negocio viajamos principalmente a la clase ObtenerEmpresa.java dentro de esta tengo un metodo donde obtengo todos los datos que muestro en dicho splash el codigo es el siguiente:

```
public void DatosEmpresa(){

        String URL = "http://pedidoslab.6te.net/consultas/obtenerEmpresa.php";

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(SplashPrincipal.this);

        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,

                response -> {

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Empresa");

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            gNombreEmpresa = jsonObject1.getString("nombre_empresa");
                            tvEmpresa.setText(gNombreEmpresa);

                            gCorreoEmpresa = jsonObject1.getString("correo_empresa");

                            gLogoEmpresa = jsonObject1.getString("logo_empresa");
                            Glide.with(this).load(gLogoEmpresa).into(imgEmpresa);

                            gFacebookEmpresa = jsonObject1.getString("facebook_empresa");

                            gAnimacionEmpresa = jsonObject1.getString("animacion_empresa");
                            Glide.with(this).load(gAnimacionEmpresa).into(animacionEmpresa);

                            gRedEmpresa = jsonObject1.getInt("red");
                            gGreenEmpresa = jsonObject1.getInt("green");
                            gBlueEmpresa = jsonObject1.getInt("blue");

                            tvEmpresa.setTextColor(Color.rgb(gRedEmpresa, gGreenEmpresa, gBlueEmpresa));

                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                , error -> Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()) {};
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }
```

Como se habrán dado cuenta este método me sirve para obtener los datos de la empresa por el momento solo me trae los datos de una base de datos sin embargo la finalidad es que me traiga los datos dependiendo de la base de datos seleccionada.

Segun la solucion de @Francisco Nuñez hice lo siguiente:

Mi archivo php de conexion:

```
<?php

function dbConnector($params){

$root = $params['root'];
$usuario = $params['usuario'];
$password = $params['password'];
$base = $params['base'];

$mysqli = new mysqli($root, $usuario, $password, $base);

if($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    die("Fallo la conexion");
} else {
   return $mysqli;
}
}

$mysqli = dbConnector([
                    'root'=> '',
                    'usuario'=> '',
                    'password'=> '',
                    'base'=> ''
                    ]);

?>
```

Y en el adapter de android declare el codigo para enviar el parametro:

```
negociosViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Obtener el id del negocio
            ObtenerNegocios.idNegocio = listaNegocios.get(posicion).getIdNegocio();

            try {

                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

                URL url = new URL("http://pedidoslab.6te.net/consultas/conn.php");
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("root", "mi localhost"));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("usuario", "mi usuario"));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "mi password"));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("base", " mi base de datos"));

                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(getQuery(params));
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();

                conn.connect();
            }catch (IOException e){

            }
            System.out.println("El id de negocio es: " + ObtenerNegocios.idNegocio);

            //Intencion al splash dependiendo del id del negocio y la conexion
            cContext.startActivity(new Intent(cContext, SplashPrincipal.class));

        }
    });
```

Y pues creo que eso seria todo, como siempre espero que se haya comprendido la pregunta y la explicación si no es así por favor ayudarme a editar, si necesitan mas código también decirme, de antemano muchas gracias y feliz día.

Comment: el archivo de conexión a la base de datos esta mal. no debes dejar vacios los datos de conexion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En realidad tu puedes crear una librería de conexión y pasarle los parámetros en tiempo real o tiempo de ejecución, de esta manera puedes enviar la conexión a la base de datos que deseas en ese momento y no una fija.

**conn.php**

```
<?php

function dbConnector($params){
    $root = $params['root'];
    $usuario = $params['usuario'];
    $password = $params['password'];
    $base = $params['base'];

    $mysqli = new mysqli($root, $usuario, $password, $base);

    if($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        die("Fallo la conexion");
    } else {
        return $mysqli;
    }
}

?>
```

**ObtenerEmpresa.php**

```
<?php

require "conn.php";
// en este array puedes remplazar los valores por los que recibas de Android Studio o tu app y de tal manera lograras una conexión dinámica
$mysqli = dbConnector([
                        'root'=>'Mi localhost',
                        'usuario'=>'Mi usuario',
                        'password'=>'Mi contraseña',
                        'base'=>'El nombre de mi base de datos'
                        ]);



$sql = "SELECT nombre_empresa, logo_empresa, correo_empresa, facebook_empresa, animacion_empresa, red, green, blue FROM empresa";
$query = $mysqli->query($sql);

$datos = array();

while($resultado = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $datos[] = $resultado;
}

echo json_encode(array("Empresa" => $datos));

mysqli_close($mysqli);

?>
```

***Lo que no vi en tu código si lo has intentado, es enviar de Android Studio a PHP las 4 variables de Conexión.***

hay dos maneras de comunicar android con un servidor que ejecute php:

1. hacerlo por cmd si estan en la misma plataforma.
2. hacerlo con un http request.

explicare la segunda por que no tengo ejemplo de la primera y la segunda es la mas habitual para mi entender:

```
URL url = new URL("http://yoururl.com");
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);

List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "Chatura"));

OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
writer.write(getQuery(params));
writer.flush();
writer.close();
os.close();

conn.connect();
```

donde `params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "Chatura"));` agrega las variables a ser enviadas al servidor php [link de la documentación](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32644195/4717133).

Lo ultimo que comentaste es que usas volley en ese caso los parámetros se agregan así:

```
public class LoginRequest extends Request<String> {

    // ... other methods go here

    private Map<String, String> mParams;

    public LoginRequest(String param1, String param2, Listener<String> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(Method.POST, "http://test.url", errorListener);
        mListener = listener;
        mParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
        mParams.put("paramOne", param1);
        mParams.put("paramTwo", param2);

    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return mParams;
    }
}
```

Documentación relacionada a Volley:
[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16639438/4717133)

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por responder, parece que logro comprender lo que me tratas de decir algo que no comprendo es como le pasaría una base de datos distinta a la librería? y luego obtenerla desde Android Studio. Conforme a lo que me comentas de ultimo: Lo que no vi en tu código si lo has intentado, es enviar de Android Studio a PHP las 4 variables de Conexión. Eso aun no lo he hecho y curiosamente eso es lo que alguien me comento pasar las variables de conexión desde Android, te agradecería si me compartes un ejemplo o un link para buscar mas información al respecto, de antemano muchas gracias

Comment: @AdielMoran  para poder ayudarte mas debes decir como ejecutas desde android estudio `ObtenerEmpresa.php` eso si lo haces cierto?

Comment: Hola, comentarte que ya he modificado lo la pregunta y he agregado el código donde obtengo los datos de la empresa con una pequeña explicación espero sea suficiente para que logres comprender de mejor manera mi código

Comment: Hola, sinceramente te agradezco mucho el tiempo que te has tomado en ayudarme, esto es mas que suficiente para empezar a trabajar, saludos.

Comment: si ya te agregue en mi respuesta dos metodos para trabajar el request, usando httprequest o Map y HashMap...

Comment: Muchas gracias !!

Comment: Hola disculpa la molestia tengo un problema al momento de mandar la variables a PHP y no encuentro forma de resolverlo, ya implemente el código en Android pero parece que no manda las variables el problema seria desde android hasta esta parte del codigo en PHP: mysqli = dbConnector([ 'root'=>'', 'usuario'=>'', 'password'=>'',  'base'=>'']); desde android seria algo asi como el HashMap pero no envia las variables sabes si en PHP tiene que ser de otra manera, tengo entendido que las varaibles de PHP tienen que quedar vacias ya que desde android les envio el valor, de antemano muchas gracias !!!!

Comment: en la primera linea del php pon esto `var_dump($_POST); die;` y me dices que te retorna al Android en response

Comment: Hola buen dia ya lo hice y me retorna lo siguiente Value array(0) of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: hasle el ouput correcto en java pues ... simplemente te esta diciendo que no puede transformarlo... te esta retornando un string...

Comment: Hola ya he modificado la pregunta con los cambios realizados quizá podrías identificar donde esta el error, muchas gracias por tu tiempo.